# Getting a uri from a bitmap

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a uri from a bitmap so that I can upload it to Firebase's storage, but my `path` keeps coming back as null. After some googling, I tried adding  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` to my manifest to fix it, but it didn't have any effect. Whenever I debug my program in android studio, it seems to break when creating `path`.

Here's the code:

```java
private Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap myImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), myImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

This an example of how I am using the method

```java
Uri file = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), uploadPhoto);
StorageReference picRef = storageRef.child("images/" + file.getLastPathSegment());
// Uploads the file
UploadTask uploadTask = picRef.putFile(file);
```

Comment: You are doing nothing with `bytes` so why is it there? And you should use the whole uri and not only a last segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the image in memory, why do you even need a reference to its path on disk? Just directly upload the image